# CSV if row contains string append row

Tags: python, csv

I am trying to append a row in sitemap_bp.csv in the adjacent column, if a line contains a string from mobilesitemap-browse.csv.
I'm not able to iterate through the lines in mobilesitemap-browse.csv, it gets stuck on the first line.  How do I go about solving this?

```
import csv

with open('sitemap_bp.csv','r') as csvinput:
    with open('mobilesitemap-browse.csv','r') as csvinput2:
        with open('output.csv', 'w') as csvoutput:
            writer = csv.writer(csvoutput, lineterminator='\n')
            sitemap = csv.reader(csvinput)
            mobilesitemap = csv.reader(csvinput2)

            all = []
            row = next(sitemap)
            row.append('mobile')
            all.append(row)

            for mobilerow in mobilesitemap:
                for row in sitemap:
                    #print row[0]
                    if mobilerow[1] in row[0]:
                        #print row, mobilerow[1]
                        all.append((row[0], mobilerow[1]))
                    else:
                        all.append(row)

            writer.writerows(all)
```

Comment: This is an aside, but don't use the nested `with` expressions. You can chain them with commas, e.g. `with open('file1.txt') as file1, open('file2.txt') as file2, ...`

Comment: Thank you for the data. Could you show us the output you're ACTUALLY getting? I think the expected output is clear enough

Comment: Updated snippet of sitemap_bp.csv, Am currently using `\d{4,}_\d{4,}_\d{4,}_\d{4,}_\d{4,}|\d{4,}_\d{4,}_\d{4,}_\d{4,}|\d{4,}_\d{4,}_\d{4,}|\d{4,}` to capture new types.

Comment: That's a silly regex. Just do `r"\d{4,}(?:_\d{4,})*"`

Comment: Works for me! https://regex101.com/r/dH2nM7/1

Comment: Yeah, I forgot the `*`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72869/discussion-between-e-liquid-vape-and-adam-smith).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally I'd parse the data from sitemap_bp.csv first, then use that dictionary to populate the new file.

```
import re

with open('sitemap_bp.csv','r') as csvinput, \
        open('mobilesitemap-browse.csv','r') as csvinput2, \
        open('output.csv', 'w') as csvoutput:
    writer = csv.writer(csvoutput, lineterminator='\n')
    sitemap = csvinput # no reason to pipe this through csv.reader
    mobilesitemap = csv.reader(csvinput2)

    item_number = re.compile(r"\d{5}_\d{7}_{7}")

    item_number_mapping = {item_number.search(line).group(): line.strip()
                           for line in sitemap if item_number.search(line)}
    # makes a dictionary {item_number: full_url, ...} for each item in sitemap
    # alternate to the above, consider:
    # # item_number_mapping = {}
    # # for line in sitemap:
    # #     line = line.strip()
    # #     match = item_number.search(line)
    # #     if match:
    # #         item_number_mapping[match.group()] = match.string

    all = [row + [item_number_mapping[row[1]] for row in mobilesitemap]

    writer.writerows(all)
```

My guess is that after the first time through your outer `for` loop, it tries to iterate through `sitemap` again but can't since the file is already exhausted. The minimal change for that would be:

```
        for mobilerow in mobilesitemap:
            csvinput.seek(0) # seek to the start of the file object
            next(sitemap) # skip the header row
            for row in sitemap:
                #print row[0]
                if mobilerow[1] in row[0]:
                    #print row, mobilerow[1]
                    all.append((row[0], mobilerow[1]))
                else:
                    all.append(row)
```

But the obvious reason not to do this is that it iterates through your `sitemap_bp.csv` file once per row in `mobilesitemap-browse.csv`, rather than just once like my code.

#### EDIT per question in comments

If you need to get a list of those URLs in `sitemap_bp.csv` that don't correspond with `mobilesitemap-browse.csv`, you're probably best-served by making a `set` for all the items you see as you see them, then using set operations to get the unseen items. This takes a little tinkering, but...

```
# instead of all = [row + [item number ...

seen = set()
all = []

for row in mobilesitemap:
    item_no = row[1]
    if item_no in item_number_mapping:
        all.append(row + [item_number_mapping[item_no]])
        seen.add(item_no)
# after this for loop, `all` is identical to the list comp version
unmatched_items = [item_number_mapping[item_num] for item_num in
                   set(item_number_mapping.keys()) - seen]
```

Comment: TY, one thing i need in 'all = []'  is the URLs(from sitemap) that do not have a corresponding match, what is the best way to do this? Do I need to iterate through sitemap?

Comment: @EliquidVape you mean all the URLs in `sitemap_bp.csv` or the URLs in `mobilesitemap-browse.csv`?

Comment: All the URLs in sitemap_bp.csv